# MATLAB: Image Snapshot arrays

Tags: matlab

A cell array was invoked to store snapshots from a Logitech USB camera:

```
obj=videoinput('winvideo',1)
disp(obj.name)
MJPG_1024x576-winvideo-1
```

Execution required 33 seconds.

```
tic
nframes=25;
frame=cell(nframes);
for i=1:nframes
    frame{i} = getsnapshot(obj);
end
toc
```

The frame (image) returned by getsnapshot() is 576X1024X3 uint8 (RGB?).

Is there a better or alternative to a cell-array [MATLAB class](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/fundamental-matlab-classes.html) to store an array of snapshots? A concrete code example is always appreciated?

Comment: If all of the images are the same size, why don't you use a multidimensional array?

Comment: Please provide an coded example in an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normal multidimensional arrays are usually faster than cell arrays:

```
tic
nframes=25;
frame=zeros(576,1024,3,nframes,'uint8');
for i=1:nframes
    frame(:,:,:,i) = getsnapshot(obj);
end
toc
```

Afterwards, accessing an individual frame is the same as the assignment: `frame(:,:,:,frame_num)` gives you a 572x1024x3 array. Only benchmarks will tell if this method is truly faster.

Comment: I thought it would please you to know that the execution was reduced an order of magnitude from 33 to 3 seconds.  I suspect the performance increase is due to pre-allocation of the matrix  with the zeros statement and avoiding the Cell matrix type

Comment: Cell arrays are notoriously slow. I try to avoid them unless absolutely necessary.